# Função que escreva os primeiros 50 números cuja soma dos dígitos formantes é 10

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

Tenho uma dúvida, estou precisando fazer uma função em JavaScript que mostre os 50 números que a soma dos seus dígitos seja igual a 10, exemplo:

Número 19, dígitos 1 e 9, soma dos dígitos: 1+9 =10. A função deve me mostrar o número 19, mostrando um total de 50 números.

Eu consegui, a princípio, calcular os dígitos do número, usando uma *form*, só não consegui desenvolver a lógica para mostrar os 50 números.

```
function start()  {
    var form = document.getElementById("exercicio_8");
        var x = form.num_5.value;
        var y = x.toString().split("");
        var soma = eval(y.join('+'));
        document.getElementById("saida2").innerHTML = soma;   
}
```

Comment: Não entendi como seu código atual funciona (qual é a entrada?), nem onde está o problema... Poderia [edit] a pergunta incluindo mais detalhes?

Comment: Pelo que deu a entender, ele não tem ideia de como montar a lógica pra exibir essa lista com 50 nums

Comment: a entrada esta num form, a variavel x esta vindo de um input, nesse caso, eu to digitando um numero num form, exemplo: 26, e ele ta me dando a soma dos digitos, 2+6 =8, mas o renan ja respondeu a pergunta, obrigado

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eu imagino algo do tipo:

```
var numeros = [];
var contador = 0;
while (numeros.length < 50) {
    var acumulador = 0;
    var algarismos = (contador + "").split("");
    for (var i = 0; i < algarismos.length; i++) {
        acumulador += parseInt(algarismos[i]);
    }
    if (acumulador === 10) {
        numeros.push(contador);
    }
    contador++;
}
```

Quando isso aí acabar, é só exibir o conteúdo de `numeros` em algum lugar. Pode transformar o conteúdo desse *Array* em uma *string* usando `numeros.join(", ")`, por exemplo.

BTW para efeitos de prova, o resultado deve ser esse:

```
[19, 28, 37, 46, 55, 64, 73, 82, 91, 109,
 118, 127, 136, 145, 154, 163, 172, 181,
 190, 208, 217, 226, 235, 244, 253, 262,
 271, 280, 307, 316, 325, 334, 343, 352,
 361, 370, 406, 415, 424, 433, 442, 451,
 460, 505, 514, 523, 532, 541, 550, 604]
```

**edição**: depois de reler a pergunta, acho que seu problema é com laços. O pulo do gato aqui é a palavra chave `while` ;)

Comment: Eu estava trabalhando numa solução estilo força-bruta bem parecida: http://jsfiddle.net/63uhw/

Comment: isso ai que eu queria mesmo, valeu pela resposta! vou entender a logica que voce usou para os proximos exercicios

Answer (score 4):

Apesar de as respostas já resolverem o problema, vou deixar uma opção usando apenas um `loop` e [array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
 var numeros = []; // para armazenar os números
 // sabemos que o primeiro número é 19, portanto loop inicia em 19
 for (var i = 19; numeros.length < 50 ;i++){ 
    //separa os algarismos
    var alg = i.toString().split("");
    // reduce aplica uma função em cada valor do array da esquerda para direita 
    var sum = alg.reduce(function(a,b){
       return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
    });
    // if else ternário, adiciona ao array se atender a condição
    sum == 10 && numeros.push(i); 
 }
 //imprime os números no body separados por vírgula
 document.body.innerHTML = numeros.join(', ');
```

[Exemplo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fPjK9/)

Comment: Virei seu fã! +1

Comment: Valeu, anotei aqui os codigos para uso futuro e entendimento!

Comment: +1 Só um complemento: a princípio não é necessário separar a string com `.split("")`, pois uma string em JavaScript é equivalente a um array em que cada elemento é uma string de 1 caractere. Não dá pra fazer `i.toString().reduce` porque `String` não herda de `Array`, mas pode-se fazer `Array.prototype.reduce.call(i.toString(), ...` (ou simplesmente `[].reduce.call(i.toString(), ...`).

Comment: @mgibsonbr interessante, obrigado passarei utilizar assim.

Answer (score 3):

Apesar de que a resposta do Renan faz a tarefa principal, se sua dificuldade é em integrar com o que você já tem, este código deve ser mais fácil de você adaptar:

```
    function start()  {
        var cont = 0;
        var x = 1;
        do {
            // Aproveitando uma parte do seu código:
            var y = x.toString().split("");
            var soma = eval(y.join('+'));

            // Algumas alterações daqui pra baixo:
            if(soma == 10){
                document.getElementById("saida2").innerHTML += ", " + x;
                cont++;
            }
            // x precisa ser iterado, e não entrado pelo usuário:
            x++;
        } while(cont < 50);

        // Ajuste final: precisamos remover a vírgula sobrando no começo:
        document.getElementById("saida2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("saida2").innerHTML.substr(2);
        // Comente a linha acima para entender o que eu estou falando!
    }
```

Procurei facilitar o entendimento, mas obviamente o código pode ser reestruturado de maneira mais profissional, como o do Renan. Também não entendi o motivo da sua input, acredito que você deseje imprimir os 50 primeiros números que atendem à condição: "A soma dos algarismos deve ser igual a 10".

Espero que ajude.

Comment: a input foi um teste que eu estava fazendo com o codigo, ver se realmente o split e o join estavam somando os digitos. Como faz pouco tempo que comecei a fazer javascript, faco testes com input para depois aplicar a logica. Valeu pela resposta!

Comment: Opa! Ah, entendi, achei que esse já era o código final, por isso o comentário em cima do "x++" e o getElementById :D
A resposta do Renan está mais limpa e usável, então! Por nada, abraços!